# Rails: How to show validation error messages while updating multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am updating multiple records in rails using below syntax

```
@user = Model.update(params[:user].keys,params[:user].values)
```

Records are updated successfully. But if there is any **validation error** then I am not able to see it via `@user.errors` .

I am getting error as `NoMethodError (undefined method errors' for #<Array:0x6dff140>):`

How can i display error message if any of the record is not saved due to errors while editing multiple records??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any error messages that get generated via the validation process are accessible from each model instance. When you run the update method in your example, it is returning to the @user variable an array of model instances that were updated. Therefore, you can examine the model instances 'within' the array to check if it has errors and not the array itself which is what you are doing currently.

Answer (score -3):

```
@users = Model.update(params[:user].keys,params[:user].values)
@errors = @users.map(&:errors).select(&:present?)
```